# Font Awesome doesn't work in MS Office on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, fonts, microsoft-word-2011, microsoft-office-2011

I've just installed Font Awesome as a system font on my Mac (OS X 10.6.8), and it doesn't seem to work in Microsoft Office 2011 (14.2.3). It installs correctly, appears in Font Book, and works as expected in TextEdit, Evernote, and LibreOffice; but in Word or Excel, it doesn't appear in the list of available fonts, and if I past Font Awesome content in from another document, it displays in the default font. I've tried using both the .ttf and .otf versions (uninstalling the first before installing the second), and get exactly the same results.

Any ideas? I was hoping to use some of the icons in a spreadsheet of gaming data.

Comment: I have the same problem and I noticed that the drop-down menu for the font selection displays "Fontawesome" when pasting an icon from the fontawesome cheat sheet.

edit: apparently Office doesn't support other fonts than its own: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. As per [the Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295062) John Christopher linked to, Microsoft Office for Mac doesn't support *any* third-party fonts. This is mind-boggling. It looks like the solution is just to use LibreOffice, or else find a Windows machine.